# Maven Project Failed to Build in Eclipse

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I created a demo maven project from `start.spring.io`, and I tried to run `mvn clean package` from Eclipse, but it gave me the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.6.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Development\demo\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentpath:"C:\Windows\system32\Aternity\Java\JavaHookLoader.dll"="C:\ProgramData\Aternity\hooks"
```

Anyone knows the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Network/firewall/proxy issue: `Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org`...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by adding the `settings.xml` in the `.m2` folder.